# How To Get Id from Spinner in Retrofit Using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a form using spinner, the data spinner I get from database using retrofit 2 , I have a field id_employee and employee_name, I would like to show employee_name but id_fish that saved in database.

I success to show the employee_name in android spinner but when i want to save the form into database is id_employee , how to save id_employee while the displayed in spinner is employee_name example :

```
<select>
  <option value="001">Brad Smith</option>
  <option value="002">Wanda</option>
  <option value="003">John Doe</option>
<select>
```

MySpinner :

```
private initSpinner()
{
List<DataEmployee> dataEmployee= response.body().getData();
List<String> idEmployee = new ArrayList<String>();
                    List<String> employeeName = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataEmployee.size(); i++){

                        idEmployee.add(dataFish.get(i).getId_employee());
                        employeeName.add(dataEmployee.get(i).getEmployee_name());
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LelangActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, employeeName);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerEmployee.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is spinner SetOnclickListener :

```
spinnerFish.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String fishName= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
 spinnerFish.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                          String  Fishname= datafish.get(i).getId_employee();


                    }
                });
```